# Migratordotnet : How to write a migration class with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, migration, migratordotnet

I got all C# implementations on Google, so I converted it to VB.Net, but I am not able to convert 1 line where it gives error.

My Class :

```
Imports Migrator.Framework

[Migration(1)]     ' Gives ERROR Here.. How to write this in VB.net ?

Public Class mig_001
    Inherits Migration

    Public Overrides Sub Up()
        Database.AddTable("Planets",
            New Column("Id", DbType.Int32, ColumnProperty.PrimaryKeyWithIdentity),
            New Column("Name", DbType.String, 100, ColumnProperty.NotNull),
            New Column("Diameter", DbType.Double),
            New Column("Mass", DbType.Double),
            New Column("SupportsLife", DbType.Boolean, False)
        )
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Down()
        Database.RemoveTable("Planets")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Once again :

```
[Migration(1)] => How to write this in VB.net and what does it means in VB.net ?
```

I read in an article that its mandatory for version of Migration, otherwise Migratordotnet will miss the migration.

So.. How to do it ?

Comment: Incidentally, what has this got to do with VB6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
<Migration(1)> _
Public Class mig_001
```

This `<…>` feature, belonging to the following class, is called an *attribute* in .NET.

Comment: Thanks !! You saved my day.. I didn't even knew how to search for this !